# How to automatically grow SwiftUI MacOS TableColumn to fix the text

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a table as follows:

```
var body: some View {
    Table(logs, selection: $selectedLine, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
        TableColumn("timestamp", value: \.timestamp) {
            Text("\($0.timestamp.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .standard))")
        }
        TableColumn("device", value: \.level)
        TableColumn("message", value: \.message)
    }
    .onChange(of: sortOrder) {
        logs.sort(using: $0)
    }
}
```

Right now the table defaults to splitting each of the columns equally, but I would like it to set the column to fix the size of the data within.

timestamp and device are tiny compared to message, which often needs to scroll scroll to view it all.

How can I make it so that timestamp and device will shrink, and message will grow even if it means scroll would be required? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.width()` on the Table columns:

```
        Table(logs) {
            TableColumn("timestamp") { log in
                Text(log.timestamp.formatted(date: .omitted , time: .standard))
            }
            .width(100)
            TableColumn("device", value: \.level)
                .width(50)
            TableColumn("message", value: \.message)
        }
```

and if you want to size according to content you can use GeometryReader like this:

```
    @State private var colWidth: CGFloat = 100
    
    var body: some View {
        Table(logs) {
            TableColumn("timestamp") { log in
                Text(log.timestamp.formatted(date: .omitted , time: .standard))
                    .overlay( GeometryReader { geo in Color.clear.onAppear { colWidth = geo.size.width }})
            }
            .width(min: colWidth, max: colWidth)
```

**Edit: set max, but still be able to shrink**

```
    @State private var colWidth1: CGFloat?
    @State private var colWidth2: CGFloat?

    var body: some View {
        Table(logs) {
            TableColumn("timestamp") { log in
                Text(log.timestamp.formatted(date: .omitted , time: .standard))
                    .overlay( GeometryReader { geo in Color.clear.onAppear { colWidth1 = max(colWidth1 ?? 0, geo.size.width) }})
            }
            .width(ideal: colWidth1, max: colWidth1)
            
            TableColumn("device") { log in
                Text(log.level)
                    .overlay( GeometryReader { geo in Color.clear.onAppear { colWidth2 = max(colWidth2 ?? 0, geo.size.width) }})
            }
            .width(ideal: colWidth2, max: colWidth2)

            TableColumn("message", value: \.message)
                .width(ideal: 200, max: .infinity)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I updated `colWidth = geo.size.width` to `colWidth = max(colWidth, geo.size.width)` and it works. However I am unable to then resize it to smaller if I wanted to, do you know of how I could do that? I tried `.width(min: 10, ideal: colWidth)` but that then sets the width to `10` and not the calculated one. Also this doesn't seem to account for the header size, anyway to do that?

Comment: try `.width(ideal: colWidth, max: colWidth)` and set width values for all columns.

Comment: Sorry, `.width(min: 10, ideal: colWidth)` sets it to equal width for all columns (as it did originally without your changes), `.width(ideal: colWidth, max: colWidth)` sets the width to the initial value of `@State private var colWidth: CGFloat`, in my case it's 10

Comment: edited the answer: the width vars need to be optional, so it is not defining width at first view update (before the geometry readers change the value).

Comment: Yes, I think your edited version is the best solution I can find. I was kind of hoping for a way to set force the initial size to be automatic, but allow complete freedom with shrinking and growing but I don't think it would be possible from playing around a bit more with the options. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the edited version doesn't automatically grow the the message column to its max length and instead cuts it cuts it off and forces the user to expand the column